# What is the best professional email address for my own portfolio domain?

Tags: resume, email, portfolio

Ok I am a full-stack developer I do freelancer projects. 
I have a portfolio site and my domain has my own name ex: "myname.com". so what do you think a best professional email address  would be.

so I was thinking if I use my own name like this: myname@myname.com that would be weird right ? currently I have this: hello@myname.com. so I'm kind feel this is not a professional one. what do you guys think ?

> I want this address to put in my CV/Resume, I want to send this address to my clients and put it in my business card.

Comment: What exactly is not covered by the answers given to that question? Please edit that into the question.

Comment: in that duplicated question, he/she asking a what should a professional email look like. it doesn't say he has a his ow domain or anything. he want to create from a free service like gmail or yahoo. my question is totally difference. I've found almost similar question to mine but it says he needed that email to his company. so that doesn't matter, i mean his company and his name is different . please tell me what covered in that answer ?

Comment: Why isn't the content of the top three answers written there sufficient to answer your question?

Comment: well according to my question i didn't want a professional one but a suitable one. so i had a `hello@myname.com`. lot of website use that kinda emails in their contact form. it's professional and friendly  but it not suitable for in career wise. so i asked for suggestions. maybe my question is not clear enough. anyway i go my answer. thanks for your concern. :)

Comment: I'm not saying that your question cannot be reopened, I'm just asking you to clarify what the difference is. The only difference I see between this post and that one is it uses a "free" email like Gmail, while you have a custom domain name. However, the advice given there applies to your case as well, as I see it. For some reason, you believe that this is not the case, so I would like you to edit that difference into the question so that it can be considered for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with something like: `contact@myname.com`, `info@myname.com` altough having your name or your company name - depending on which you use to advertise yourself - at the begining of your email might be the best idea for the following reason.

Most of the people who will be contacting you with professional inquiries have many different contacts in their mail box/ mail client, from my own experience I know that it is a great convinience having to just type initial letters of a company I want to contact or name of a person - which I don't have to remember fully - because the mail client will suggest contacts that have been used in the past and make it much easier if I contact them only once in a while and don't remember their email. Some mailing clients might be strict on the letter placement in the email and will only look for adresses starting with the letters you type in and look for those in the domain name after the `@` sign.

In conclusion, in my opinion it is the best to have your email start with whatever you want your clients to associate you with, be it your name, your company name etc.